# Neumann-like boundary conditions for Poisson equation

Tags: elliptic-equations

Consider following problem for Poisson equation in some bounded domain $G$ with piecewise smooth Lipschitz continuious boundary $\partial G$:
$$
-\Delta u = \rho \text{ in } G\\
(\boldsymbol{\nu} \nabla) u = \sigma \text{ on } \partial G
$$
where vector $\boldsymbol{\nu}$ is neither collinear to the normal $\mathbf{n}$ nor orthogonal to it.

Assuming all required smoothness, is the problem posessed well?